# How to tell Google not to provide a Cache link?

Tags: caching, meta-tags

Google says that you can tell it to not provide a "cached" link in its search results for a page that it is crawling/indexing.

How do you tell it not to link to a cached version? Is it in a meta tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, noarchive: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812

Comment: do you know if this ends up being a negative hit on SEO, or is it just adjusting how the result is displayed?

Comment: It's certainly not detrimental to rankings by itself, but it might be used as contributing factor if the site already has other qualities that are flagging it up as a generally poor resource.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, will this reduce traffic to our website.

Comment: @ChrisHarris preventing Google from showing a 'view cached version' of your website, will reduce traffic to your website?  No, it will increase traffic to your website!

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, what do you mean by increase? Is that the same traffic?

Comment: @ChrisHarris: If people choose to view the cached version of your website, then they are viewing Google's copy of your website instead of visiting the real site.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, You don't say how this increase the traffic? Can we move to chat?

Comment: @ChrisHarris I did say, if you understand that people viewing Google's cache of your website is not your traffic.  I don't know how to move to chat.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, what do you mean by "people viewing Google's cache of your website is not your traffic". I didn't understand.

Comment: @ChrisHarris: When users view the cached version of your page, they are visiting http://webcache.googleusercontent.com and not your site.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, That's why i tell you it reduces our traffic not increasing.

Comment: @ChrisHarris You didn't tell me that before now.  I think you have misunderstood this Stack Overflow question.  This question is about how to remove the cached version from Google search results page.  This doesn't mean your site is removed from Google completely, just the link giving the option to view the page from Google's cache.  Tell me how traffic is reduced if you think you have understood properly.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, if the cache version is available just a "copy of our website in google server" is showing, not the real time website. this makes reduce in our traffic. isn't it?

Comment: @ChrisHarris yes preciely, this Stack Overflow question and my answer is about how to remove the cached version from the Search Engine Results Page.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise:

`<meta name="robots" content="noarchive"/>`